# Elasticsearch _count query request cache

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-7

Taken from docs: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.9/shard-request-cache.html#shard-request-cache

> By default, the requests cache will only cache the results of search requests where `size=0`, so it will not cache hits, but it will cache `hits.total`, `aggregations`, and `suggestions`.
>
> Most queries that use now (see Date Math) cannot be cached.
>
> Scripted queries that use the API calls which are non-deterministic, such as `Math.random()` or `new Date()` are not cached.

However how does this play with _count queries? _count queries behave almost exactly the same as _search queries with `size=0`?

I'd expect request cache to cache count queries as well, but couldn't find any information about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever the documentation doesn't tell, go to the source ;-)

In this case, if we look at the source of [`RestCountAction`](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/search/RestCountAction.java#L63-L65) (i.e. the class handling the `_count` endpoint), we can see that what it actually does is creating a `SearchRequest` with `size: 0`

```
    a search request
          |
          v
    SearchRequest countRequest = new SearchRequest(Strings.splitStringByCommaToArray(request.param("index")));
    countRequest.indicesOptions(IndicesOptions.fromRequest(request, countRequest.indicesOptions()));
    SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder().size(0).trackTotalHits(true);
                                                                          ^
                                                                          |
                                                                     with size 0
```

Furthermore, when [building the response](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/action/search/RestCountAction.java#L98) we can see that the `count` value is actually the value of `hits.total` from the `SearchResponse`:

```
    builder.field("count", response.getHits().getTotalHits().value);
```

So, from that, we can deduce that count queries are de facto cached as well.

Comment: and opster, I explicitly used the `request_cache=true` for my heavy/ costly search queries and according to doc, than it would cache the `hits` as well but even after multiple times and try on different queries, I can't see much difference in query performance

Comment: Please let me know what could be the cause, one thing I notice is that `hits.total` was also changing which as my index is also getting the write request and I feel this could be the cause as shard is getting refreshed and  cache is getting invalidated

Comment: @PrernaGupta maybe you want to create a question of your own for your specific use case? This one was not exactly about what you're asking

Comment: @PrernaGupta from the link the OP shared: `Cached results are invalidated automatically whenever the shard refreshes, but only if the data in the shard has actually changed.` so it's pretty clear that if you have write requests, the cache get's cleared

Comment: so even if data is not changed(no new indexed request) and refresh_interval is set to 1 sec(default and same in my case) search results will be removed from cache?

Comment: read again `...but only if the data in the shard has actually changed`, but you said that your index was getting write requests

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221259/discussion-between-prerna-gupta-and-val).